# How to handle multiple duration format (sometimes in days, or in hours, or in seconds) in one variable rapidly?

Tags: r, date, datetime

I have a dataframe in which a duration variable is :

```
  127 days 00:42:57.83 
  1 hour 14:53.11 
  37.52 seconds       
  1269665756
  4 hours 17:49.04 
  ...
```

All those different formats are stored in only one column of my data frame.
How to transform it easily as a unique format?

I try doing separatly:

```
  data$var[grep("days",data$var)],then data$var[grep("hours",data$var)]  and data$var[grep("seconds",data$var)]
```

and calculation on something like

```
  strsplit(data$var[grep("days",data$var)], "days")
```

But I do not know then how to make a new vector taking only the first part of each result of my strsplit.(only taking the number of days and not the part after 'days')

Comment: the duration variable is in only one column? I mean, all those different formats are stored in only one column of the data frame?

Comment: Please post some lines of your data, especially of course the column where all this durations are stored. Most likely R reads all of them as strings and the approach could be to split the data frame based on different time durations "as strings", converts each of them, and then combine them again.

Comment: This is what I wrote at the bottom of my question : I thought of extracting the different format one by one by the 'grep' function and then split them to convert it.
my column is 

     
         '127 days 00:42:57.83 '
         '1 hour 14:53.11 '
         '37.52 seconds '
         '25148953 ' ...